# Rails association field not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models in a has_one belongs_to relationship:

```
class Facility < ApplicationRecord
   has_one :machine
end


class Machine < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :facility
end
```

In the _form partial for saving machines, I have a collection_select that picks the facility:

```
<%= form.collection_select :facility, Facility.all, :id, :facility_name, 
{prompt: "Select a faclity"}, {class: "form-control"} %>
```

In the MachinesController I have facility_id permitted as shown below:

```
def machine_params
   params.require(:facsummary).permit(:facility_id, ....)
end
```

I think I have done everything right, but despite selecting a facility in the dropdown,I get the error:

> "Facility must exist"

Where could I be going wrong?

Comment: And you have this error on `create`/`update`, right? What are the params you pass? They are easily accessible in your logs.

Comment: Yes. Funnily enough I can see the facility id being identified in the logs, but it is not being saved @MarekLipka

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to the following to add `facility_id` instead of `facility`

```
<%= form.collection_select :facility_id, Facility.all, :id, :facility_name, {prompt: "Select a faclity"}, {class: "form-control"} %>
```

and the strong parameter method it would `machine` like below

```
params.require(:machine).permit(:facility_id, ....)
```

Or try if above not work

```
<%= form.collection_select(:facility_id, Facility.all, :id, :facility_name, {prompt: 'Select a faclity'}, {:class => 'form-control'})  %>
```

It's tested

Comment: Both suggestions work, but now the form is saving although the facility field is blank

Comment: and the strong parameter method it would `machine` like below

`params.require(:machine).permit(:facility_id, ....)` updated the answer

Comment: Oh that was an oversight on my part. I have it exactly that way. Form saving but with blank Facility

Comment: Make sure the id not been saved before already, put the log after submitted the form

Comment: I had created another `facilityname` field together with `facility_id` and hence the confusion. Thank you all